# MATLAB Treebagger and Random Forests

Tags: matlab, tree, random-forest

Does the `Treebagger` class in MATLAB apply Breiman's Random Forest algorithm?

If I simply use `Treebagger`, is it the same as using Random Forests, or do I need to modify some parameters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`TreeBagger` implements a bagged decision tree algorithm, rather than Random Forests specifically.

You can get `TreeBagger` to behave basically the same as Random Forests as long as the `NVarsToSample` parameter is set appropriately. See the [documentation page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/treebagger.html) for `TreeBagger`, under the `NVarsToSample` parameter, for details.

Edit: Note that in release R2015b, the `NVarsToSample` parameter has been renamed to `NumPredictorsToSample`.